# Does Reaper Shredder works with Temnotic Rifle?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

My Reaper has a Temnotic Rifle, but he is also able to use a Shredder ability.
The ability reads like this:

[image]

So, do they really mean Vektor? Or would it work with any Reaper rifle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all skills work regardless of tech level. "Vektor Rifle" is the name of the weapon class, as well as the name of the tier-1 weapon in that class. It's a little confusing.